# Why basename in Makefile does not work as expected?

Tags: makefile

```
TESTS=test/hello.c
try:
        @for t in $(TESTS); do echo $(basename $$t); done
```

Running "make" I get

```
~ make
test/hello.c
```

This is strange because I expected to get the base name "hello.c". Any explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trouble is that you're trying to use the Make directive `basename` inside the shell `for` loop. Make will expand the `$(basename ...)` statement first (so `$(basename $$t)` becomes `$t`), then pass the command

```
for t in test/hello.c; do echo $t; done
```

to the shell.

This will give `test/hello`:

```
@for t in $(basename $(TESTS)); do echo $$t; done
```

and this will give `hello.c`:

```
@for t in $(notdir $(TESTS)); do echo $$t; done
```

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. What would be the solution for printing out the base name from Makefile then

Comment: Use `$$(basename $(TESTS))`

Comment: @jsp: That invokes the *shell* `basename` function. I assumed the OP wanted to use the *Make* `basename` function.